# Building Qt 5.12 LTS for Android with SSL and SQL support

Tags: android, c++, sql, qt, ssl

With google deprecating GCC, Qt 5.12 for Android makes a transition away from it in favor of Clang. Which renders the existing building guides obsolete, as they are all GCC based.

The stock Qt build for Android is lacking some important functionality, and furthermore, the related documentation seems to be fairly outdated.

Additionally, 5.12 launches with a [critical Android related bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72101), which pretty much mandates a custom build to incorporate the fix for the time being.

I myself haven't previously used Clang at all, and I am one of those people who really prefer to just make applications rather than to go through the often excruciatingly frustrating experience of trying to build the requisite tools.

Qt on Clang is here to stay, and 5.12 being a long term support release, I think a detailed step by step guide how to produce a working Qt build will be of benefit to a lot of people. It would definitely save me days of headaches and setbacks, and so I am willing to offer a generous bounty to the first reproducible answer, in addition to any bounties that may be required to promote the question visibility.

My personal requirements are SSL, MySQL and PostgreSQL support, although additional functionality is welcome. It would seem that a Linux based guide will be the most beneficial format, as it is also applicable to windows via MSYS.

Comment: Check on this: 1) [Adding OpenSSL Support for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-openssl-support.html) 2) [SQL Database Drivers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reply for all your requests, but I can say something about openssl:

Firstoff, even with Qt 5.12, if you are using the official android builds downloaded from Qt itself (via the Maintenancetool), then you still have to use the gcc toolchain and openssl 1.0.2. The Qt builds require 1.0.* and clang support has only been added to openssl since 1.1.1. Support for this version of openssl will hopefully come with Qt 5.13. See [QTBUG-71391](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71391) for more details.

---

That beeing said, if you cross-compile Qt for Android yourself (or visit this post in the future, when Qt supports this), you can use openssl 1.1 and use clang to compile it.

The steps are documented on their github in [NOTES.ANDROID](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.ANDROID). The steps are relatively straight forward and boil down to a few changes to PATH in order to build the library. A basic script, with switches for all android architectures provided by Qt, would be:

```
TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9
HOST_ARCH=linux-x86_64
case "$ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH" in
    arm64-v8a)
        API_VERSION=21
        ARCH_ID=android-arm64
        TOOLCHAIN=aarch64-linux-android-$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION
        ;;
    armeabi-v7a)
        API_VERSION=16
        ARCH_ID=android-arm
        TOOLCHAIN=arm-linux-android-$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION
        ;;
    x86)
        API_VERSION=16
        ARCH_ID=android-x86
        TOOLCHAIN=x86-$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unsupported ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH: $ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

export ANDROID_NDK=/path/to/ndk
export PATH=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST_ARCH/bin/:$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/$TOOLCHAIN/prebuilt/$HOST_ARCH/bin:$PATH
./Configure $ARCH_ID shared no-ssl3 -D__ANDROID_API__=$API_VERSION
make SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER= SHLIB_EXT=.so build_libs
```

In this script, `ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH` is simply the value of the qmake variable with the same name, so this script could be invoked by qmake. The steps that need to be done in detail are:

1. Prepare some variables:

   - TOOLCHAIN_VERSION: Simply the version of the gcc toolchain to be used (yes, this is still needed, as some tools, linke ranlib etc. are still used from there). As of NDK v18 the toolchain version is still 4.9
   - HOST_ARCH: The architecture of the host system. The sample sets this to linux. If you are on window/macos adjust this accordingly.
   - API_VERSION: The Android SDK version openssl should build for. I set the values to the version that Qt uses for builds for these plattforms, but other versions should be fine as well
   - ARCH_ID: The name of the android architecture as used by openssl
   - TOOLCHAIN: The name of the gcc toolchain to be used
2. Ensure the `ANDROID_NDK` environment variable is set to wherever you installed the NDK
3. Update the path to contain both, the clang/llvm toolchain *and* the gcc toolchain for your specific plattform. In the script, the locations of the toolchains are derived from the previous variables
4. Explicitly run the `Configure` script - and **not** `config`. Pass the target architecture and additional flags. (I for example prefer to disable ssl3 for security reasons)
5. Run make to build the library. The `SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER= SHLIB_EXT=.so` part is needed to ensure that the binaries created do not have a version number as part of their name, as android does not support that.

And thats it!

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go. Maybe we will be able to meed all the requirements with input from multiple users.